# Threading and Synchronization

Tags: java, eclipse, thread-synchronization

I need to create a java program for the following:

1. Create an ArrayList to store the names of the employees.
2. Create two synchronized methods to add the employee names to the ArrayList and print the employee names.
3. Print the employee names once both the threads have finished adding the employees.

I have done the following but it is not working.It is giving an exception at line "pr.print(X)".Can anyone help? THIS IS NOT MY HOMEWORK!!! am just trying to learn.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ch5Ex2 
 {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
    Print pri = new Print();
    pri.start();
    Insert in = new Insert(li);
    in.start();
   }
}   

class Insert extends Thread
{
 Print pr = new Print();
 List<String> x;
 public Insert(List<String> x)
  {
    this.x = x;
  }

public synchronized void run()
 {
    try
    {
      x.add("robin");
      x.add("ravi");
      x.add("raj");
      pr.print(x);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }

}

class Print extends Thread
{
 List<String> y;
public void print(List<String> y)
 {
    this.y = y;
    notify();
 }

public synchronized void run()
 {
    try
    {
     wait();
     for(int i=0;i<y.size();i++)
      {
         System.out.println(y.get(i));
      }
     }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Why am I getting negative votes for my post when I am just asking a small query after doing everything?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov I instantiated pr but now it is not printing anything

Comment: I didn't downvote, but NPE would tell exactly the line where it happens, so you could easily solve it, instead you are dumping code here.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov I said that I instantiated pr as u asked me to.I am not getting the NPE anymore but am also not getting the output yet.Am just asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think you need this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ch5Ex2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
        Print pri = new Print();
        pri.start();
        Insert in = new Insert(li, pri);
        in.start();
    }
}


class Insert extends Thread {
    Print pr;
    List<String> x;
    public Insert(List<String> x, Print p) {
        this.x = x;
        pr = p;
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        try{
            x.add("robin");
            x.add("ravi");
            x.add("raj");
            pr.print(x);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Print extends Thread {
    List<String> y;
    public synchronized void print(List<String> y) {
        this.y = y;
        notify();
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            while(y == null){
                wait();
            }
            for(int i=0;i<y.size();i++) {
                System.out.println(y.get(i));
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now this should work...

Solution is: As you are doing `wait()` in `Print thread` on `pri object` created in `main()` method, you must `notify()` to this `pri object` in order to make `Print thread` go ahead. Also if `notify()` is called before `Print thread` starts, it will make `y` in `Print` to `non-null` and your `Print thread` will not do `wait()` in that case.. :)

Comment: have you tried running above code? try it few more times.. also this is not correct solution, but it must work if Print thread starts before Insert thread. I getting output..

Comment: Okay I got the answer when I removed the wait and notify...I'll find where to place them properly and then see whether I still get the answer or not...thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess `pr` is null in `Insert` class, you never call constructor.

Comment: I instantiated pr now but it is not printing anything

Answer (score 0):

To make your life easier you may forget about synchronization on your application level and just create sychronized `ArrayList` via call to `Collections#synchronizedList()` like this

List yourArray = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList())

In that case all calls to `yourArray` from separate threads will be synchronized.
Besides that looks like `pr` is null as you never instantiate it (Thanks to @**Nikolay Kuznetsov**).

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating memory for pr.You are just creating a variable Print pr.So you must be getting NPE